# What is the basis/rationale for the barristers' cab rank rule?

Tags: england-and-wales, lawyer, barristers

Does it only apply to barristers or also solicitors? Why or why not?

Comment: This question would be improved by a brief statement of what the "barristers cab-rank rule" is, and perhaps when it applies.

Answer (score 5):

- What is the basis/rationale for the cab rank rule?

> The cab rank rule has been a defining feature of the English Bar for several hundred years. It original purpose was to ensure that parties to a case would obtain representation regardless of the predilection of the barrister to take the person as a client. There were periods, such as during the IRA bombing of mainland Britain in the 1970s, when defence
> counsel were difficult to come by. The cab rank rule was invoked by the Bar to ensure defendants had counsel in court... [Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://legalservicesboard.org.uk/wp-content/media/Cab-Rank-Rule_final-copy.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJ-Oajxq_3AhVzoFwKHc0GDZMQFnoECAUQBg&usg=AOvVaw0zdOloEoiJH5-vCNN1Vli0)

- Why not solicitors?

Because barristers and solicitors operate under their own, distinct sets of rules.

The "cab rank rule", found at [rC29 of the Bar Standards Handbook](https://www.barstandardsboard.org.uk/the-bsb-handbook.html?part=&audience=&q=Rc29),  is specific to barristers called to the Bar. Solicitors do not have a comparable rule or requirement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138877/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-what-is-the-basis-rationale-for-the-barristers-cab).