# By which "institutional mechanism" is the barristers' cab rank rule administered?

Tags: united-kingdom, barristers

User @ohwilleke mentions in another question convent thread that barristers work on a coordinated system of assigning cases to lawyers which constitutes an institutional mechanism for enforcing the cab rank rule. What is this system?

Ref: [What is the basis/rationale for the barristers' cab rank rule?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79631/what-is-the-basis-rationale-for-the-barristers-cab-rank-rule#comment170580_79634)

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79631/what-is-the-basis-rationale-for-the-barristers-cab-rank-rule

Comment: On it again @SteveMelnikoff!

Comment: Doesn't this duplicate https://law.stackexchange.com/q/79631/

Comment: I would say no.

Answer (score -1):

### The cab rank rule is imposed by government

Specifically, the regulator, the [Bar Standards Board](https://www.barstandardsboard.org.uk/for-the-public.html) under the Law Services Act 2007, has [rules](https://www.barstandardsboard.org.uk/uploads/assets/f0d114af-9c5a-4be4-9dbffa9f80b1e47f/14c70470-a550-46de-81b94d730fa4b11f/Part-2-Code-of-Conduct18092019092228.pdf). The “cab rank” rule is rC29.

Comment: But how is the particular rule implemented/enforced?

Comment: @JosephP. It’s not a complicated rule - if you approach a barrister to represent you, they can’t say no. It’s not a literal queue.

Comment: Okay so is @ohwilleke simply wrong about the "coordinated system" to which he refers?